# Can a file be opened, read, edited, output into a .txt file and repeated multiple times in a program?

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have had an idea for a program to create a text / console output game. I wanted to make the game solely in the console output using `cout` but had a different idea.

I understand that a program can open a file, read the information, edit / manipulate the information and output that information into a different file. So something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void fileWrite(int Health);  // Prototype for fileWrite

int main()
{  
  string inFile = "inFile.txt";
  string outFile = "outFile.txt";
  int Health = 100;

  ifstream fin;
  ofstream fout;

  fin.open("inFile.txt");
  fout.open("outFile.txt);

  while (!fin.oef())
  {
   fin >> Health;
   fileWrite(Health);
  }

 fin.close();
 fout.close();
 return 0;
}

void fileWrite(int Health)
{ 
 fout << setw(10) << left << "Health" << endl;
 fout << setw(10) << left << Health << endl;
}
```

So let's say `inFile.txt` simply has `50` in the file.
Like so:

```
50
```

In theory, the file should be read, `health` is now set to `50`, the function `fileWrite` is called and the output should look like this in the `outFile.txt`

```
Health:
50
```

So what I am wanting to do is make it so that say instead of reading in a file for the health, could I modify `Health` multiple times during the duration of the program and call `fileWrite`? Say that health pertains to the main character, and I create a variable named `potion` and it does +20 towards health, could I open the file. See that the character has `50` health, output the information into the `outFile.txt` then take `potion` which would increase the health to `70` and reprint the file?

The reason I am trying to find a way to do this is so that the user can use the console for inputting commands, and have the .txt file show the results of the commands.

Can a `function` be created to handle the printing and be called multiple times in main?

Comment: Yes, yes you can.

Comment: `fin.oef()` typo and not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Yes you can, but it will be woefully inefficient, and not very nice to the disk either.

Comment: So what would there be a different way to produce the same effect?